# Login failed for user Test_web'. code first

Tags: code-first

heelo this is my connection string

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient;Password=;User ID=;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
```

and this is my error please help me
Cannot open database "DataLayer.Context.test" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'test\test_web'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified the "DefaultConnection" as name of the connection string here. so your context class should have the same name. (it's the default convention in ef code-first)